# Python error on building Dart on Windows

Tags: python, windows, dart

I'm trying to build Dart on Windows XP (according to the docs) but while using Python to do it, it encounters an error in the script file:

```
D:\Documents and settings\xxx\Mes documents\Google_Dart\dart>python tools/bui
ld.py --arch=ia32
File "tools/build.py", line 51
print "Unknown mode %s" % mode
                      ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any hint on how to solve this? Can the problem be that my version of Python is too recent? (3.2.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 3 removes the `print` keyword and replaces it with a function by the same name. So, yes, that syntax is Python 2 only.